# Creating an if statement for a 2d contour plot to append lowest values

Tags: python, if-statement, plot, contour

this may be a very simple/dumb question because I'm new to coding but I have a 2d contour plot where there is an X and Y position and also an intensity at each position (Like a 2d plot with a colourbar representing the intensity at each point).
I would like to make an if statement where all points below or above a certain intensity get picked out (with their relative X and Y positions) and added to a new list which I could plot later. 
edit(sorry first time posting here)***

I have

```
'peaks = []
if abs(stack[i, i]) < -1.0 or abs(stack[i, i]) > 1.0:
    peaks.append(stack)

peaks=np.asarray(peaks)'
```

where stack is a 800 by 800 numpy array which I can use to create my contour plot
I peaks as a list which then i turn into an array but it gives me back a 1 by 800 by 800 array and I dont know where the 1 comes from.

Thank you!

Comment: `list.append` takes a single argument. Try appending tuples: `peaks.append((i, j))`. Also, please provide the full context: what `stack` is and how it looks. It it a `list` of `list`'s or a NumPy array?

Comment: Also, just for quality-of-life, `if abs(stack[i, j]) > 1.0:`